# uwsgi 1.9.18.2 some configuration only effective in app config?

Tags: django, uwsgi

I used to work in a company which has uwsgi 1.9.6 installation and the init script looks like following:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --enable-threads --single-interpreter --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --buffer-size 65536 --signal-bufsize 2097152 --logto $LOGTO --disable-logging
```

I have tried to setup an uwsgi installation on my server, which version is 1.9.18.2 and some options like `--enable-threads --single-interpreter --signal-bufsize` are not effective in the init command, and they are only effective in each app.ini as below:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
master = true
processes = 5
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=abc.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
pythonpath = /var/www/abc/abc
chdir = /var/www/abc/abc
chmod-socket = 666
uid = www-data
virtualenv = /var/www/abc
#buffer-size = 32768
vacuum = true
procname-prefix-spaced = %n
cheaper = 1
plugins = python
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
sharedarea = 4
signal-bufsize = 2097152
```

I am just wondering if this is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why but lot of people think that options added to the emperor are inherited to children/vassals. This is not true (and would be totally wrong from a technical point of view). To start an emperor you only need the --emperor option.

Your configuration (and assumption) is the right one.

If you want to pass options to vassals automatically use the techniques described in the official docs, otherwise each vassal require its options.

Comment: Is there a reason I specified 'signal-bufsize' in the app.conf and still not effect?

Comment: you need kernel tuning too to increase internal socket buffers: /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max and /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max

Comment: I see thanks, I was getting this `SIGNAL QUEUE IS FULL: buffer size 229376 bytes (you can tune it with --signal-bufsize)` but the values in /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max is 131071, they don't match?

Comment: no, the kernel proc file set the maximum value used internally and must be set higher than signal-bufsize